# Delete column based on values in two rows

Tags: excel, vba

The following code should delete the column where the values in two rows match the criteria.

There's no error, neither is it working.

```
Private Sub deleteresourcebutton_Click()
    Dim teamname As String
    Dim resourcename As String
    Dim findteamname As Range
    Dim findresourcename As Range

    teamname = teamnametextbox.Text
    resourcename = resourcenametextbox.Text

    Set findteamname = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("7:7").Find(what:=teamname, MatchCase:=False, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set findresourcename = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("8:8").Find(what:=resourcename, MatchCase:=False, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If findteamname = teamname And findresourcename = resourcename Then
        findresourcename.Select
        Selection.EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try debugging it

Comment: shows first line as non executable

Comment: Try it like this  If LCase(findteamname) = LCase(teamname) And LCase(findresourcename) = LCase(resourcename) Then

Comment: Step through your code with f8 (or put a break line on your `IF`), I image the your `IF` is not true. Also I might be wrong but you are not give `findresourcename` an address, so how does it know what to select then delete?

Comment: I've added my own answer, but just to check ... does it not matter whether the team and resource are found in the same column as each other? The code, if working, seems only to be checking that they are both found in rows 7 and 8 and then deleting the column where the resource is found (even if the team is found in a different column).

Comment: If you aren't sure the code is running at all, add a `MessageBox` or `debug.Print` statement as the first part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your `IF`. You might like to try it this way:

```
If Not (findteamname Is Nothing) And Not (findresourcename Is Nothing) Then
    findresourcename.EntireColumn.Delete
End If
```

In case there are other issues, here's a full version with some debugging added. The output from `Debug.Print` appears in the "immediate" window, so make sure that's visible in the VBE (View > Immediate Window, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)

```
Private Sub deleteresourcebutton_Click()
    'A line of code for debugging purposes
    Debug.Print "deleteresourcebutton_Click is running"

    Dim teamname As String
    Dim resourcename As String
    Dim findteamname As Range
    Dim findresourcename As Range

    teamname = teamnametextbox.Text
    resourcename = resourcenametextbox.Text

    'Two lines of code for debugging purposes
    Debug.Print "Searching for Team: " & teamname
    Debug.Print "Searching for Resource: " & resourcename

    Set findteamname = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("7:7").Find(what:=teamname, MatchCase:=False, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set findresourcename = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("8:8").Find(what:=resourcename, MatchCase:=False, lookat:=xlWhole)

    'Five lines of code for debugging purposes
    If Not (findteamname Is Nothing) Then
    Debug.Print "Team found: " & findteamname.Address
    Else
    Debug.Print "Team not found"
    End If

    If Not (findteamname Is Nothing) And Not (findresourcename Is Nothing) Then
        findresourcename.EntireColumn.Delete
    End If

    'A line of code for debugging purposes
    Debug.Print "deleteresourcebutton_Click has finished running"

End Sub
```